# Porque parece como que estoy pasando un string vacio en mi funcion?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando autocalcular campos a partir de inputs en otros campos.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="costUSD">Costo USD</label>
                <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="costUSD" class="form-control" id="cost_USD" onkeyup="CalcularMarginUSD();"  required>
            </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="list_price">Precio Lista</label>
                        <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="list_price" id="list_price" class="form-control" onkeyup="CalcularMarginUSD();"  required>
                    </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="marginUSD">Margen Bruto USD-O</label>
                        <input type="number"  id="marginUSD" step="00.01"  class="form-control" required>
                    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function CalcularMarginUSD(){
    var listPrice = document.getElementById('list_price').value;
    var cost_usd = document.getElementById('costUSD').value;
    var marginUSDO = listPrice - cost_usd;
    document.getElementById('marginUSD').value = marginUSDO; 
}


</script>
```

Donde trato de realizar la siguiente ecuacion: Margen Bruto = Precio de Lista - Costo

Pero por alguna razon obtengo el siguiente error al inspeccionar mi consola en el navegador, y no entiendo por que.

```
Cadena vacia pasada a getElementById()
```

---

```js
function CalcularMarginUSD(){
    var listPrice = document.getElementById('list_price').value;
    var cost_usd = document.getElementById('cost_USD').value;
    var marginUSDO = listPrice - cost_usd;
    document.getElementById('marginUSD').value = marginUSDO; 
   }
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="costUSD">Costo USD</label>
                    <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="costUSD" class="form-control" id="cost_USD" onkeyup="CalcularMarginUSD();"  required>
                </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <label for="list_price">Precio Lista</label>
                            <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="list_price" id="list_price" class="form-control" onkeyup="CalcularMarginUSD();"  required>
                        </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <label for="marginUSD">Margen Bruto USD-O</label>
                            <input type="number"  id="marginUSD" step="00.01"  class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Porque no usas Jquery? o debe ser solo JS "Puro"?

Comment: Un id es un identificador único para cada elemento y tienes un input con 2 id, ¿cuál es el que debe existir?, de ahí se origina tu error

Comment: Tu id en el HTML se llama `cost_USD`, pero en el JavaScript haces `document.getElementById('costUSD').value;` . Por lo tanto tu constante queda indefinida y no se puede acceder al valor de `value`. Necesitas hacer `document.getElementById('cost_USD').value;`

Comment: Consejo para la vida: etiqueta HTML a la que no le pongas etiqueta de cierre explícita (`<a>...</a>`), ciérrala. `<input ... />`, `<br />`, etc. Es una buena práctica que seguro te ahorra dolores de cabeza después.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código Arreglado:

```html
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="costUSD">Costo USD</label>
    <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="costUSD" class="form-control" id="cost_USD" onkeyup="CalcularMarginUSD();"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="list_price">Precio Lista</label>
    <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="list_price" id="list_price" class="form-control" onkeyup="CalcularMarginUSD();"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="list_price">Margen Bruto USD-O</label>
    <input type="number"  id="marginUSD" step="00.01"  class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <script>

    function CalcularMarginUSD(){
      var listPrice = document.getElementById('list_price').value;
      var cost_usd = document.getElementById('cost_USD').value;
      var marginUSDO = listPrice - cost_usd;
      document.getElementById('marginUSD').value = marginUSDO; 
    }

    </script>
```

Debes tener Cuidado con Los ID's ya que Javascript es muy Delicado en ello.

Saludos

PD: Así quedaría

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me dice "Cadena vacía pasada a getElementById()."  Y en vez de hacerme la resta, en margen bruto (donde iria el resultado de la misma) me aparece lo mismo que ingreso en el input de precio de lista. Es como si estuviese pasandole 0 todo el tiempo al costo. Ahi publique una respuesta con mi snipet

Comment: Antes que nada copia y pega el código que te pase en un archivo limpio, y ve, justo eso hice yo para conseguir el error, puede que tengas un id duplicado en tu archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que has incluido el id de un elemento en otro, pusiste el id de  `saleP` en el elemento del `Margen Bruto`, colócalo en el elemento que corresponde.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="list_price">Precio Lista</label>
  <input type="number" step="00.01" id="saleP" name="list_price" class="form-control" onkeyup="CalcularMarginUSD();" onchange="CalcularMarginUSD();" required />
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="list_price">Margen Bruto USD-O</label>
  <input type="number" id="marginUSD" step="00.01" name="list_price" class="form-control" required />
</div>
```